# Regex to remove comments endings

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex that I can use to remove any closing comment syntax out of string.

For instance if I had:

`/* help::this is my comment */` should return `this is my comment` or `<!-- help:: this is my other comment -->` should return `this is my other comment`. Ideally I would like to target all major programming languages that require ending comment tags.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function RemoveEndingTags(comment){
    return comment.split('help::')[1].replace("*/", "").replace("-->", ""); //my ugly solution
}
```

An HTML markup example would be:

```
<!-- help:: This is a comment -->
<div>Hello World</div>
```

so the string would be `help:: This is a comment -->`

Comment: When you say target major programming languages, are you meaning that the regex should be usable within those languages or simply that you want to catch the comments from major programming languages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should support many languages including bash which **doesn't support `\s`:**

```
help::[\r\n\t\f ]*(.*?)[\r\n\t\f ]*?(?:\*\/|-->)
```

You can also use **Which prevents any un-necassary selection making this easier to use also**:

```
help::[\r\n\t\f ]*(.*?)(?=[\r\n\t\f ]*?\*\/|[\r\n\t\f ]*?-->)
```

You could use this as a funky `.replace` but it might result in quirky behavior:

```
/\/\*[\r\n\t\f ]*help::|<!--[\r\n\t\f ]*help::|[\r\n\t\f ]\*\/|[\r\n\t\f ]*-->/g
```

## Explanation

### Solution 1:

```
help::            Matches the text "help::"
[\r\n\t\f ]*      Matches any whitespace character 0-unlimited times
(.*?)             Captures the text
[\r\n\t\f ]*?     Matches all whitespace
(?:               Start of non-capture group
   \*\/           Matches "*/"
|                 OR
   -->            Matches "-->"
)                 End non capture group
```

### `[\r\n\t\f ]`

```
\r Carriage return
\n Newline
\t Tab
\f Formfeed
   Space
```

### Solution 2 (supports almost everything)

```
help::             Matches "help::"
[\r\n\t\f ]*       Matches all whitespace 0-unlimited
(.*?)              Captures all text until...
(?=                Start positive lookahead
    [\r\n\t\f ]*?  Match whitespace 0-unlimited
    \*\/           Matches "*/"
|                  OR
    [\r\n\t\f ]*?  Match whitespace 0-unlimited
    -->            Matches "-->"
)
```

## [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/wW3fW2/1)

## [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/wW3fW2/2)

Comment: so if I wanted to strip it out in my string i would use `comment.replace(/help::[\r\n\t\f ]*(.*?)(?=[\r\n\t\f ]*?\*\/|[\r\n\t\f ]*?-->)/, 1);`

Comment: You would use something along the lines of `var commentText = comment.match(/help::[\r\n\t\f ]*(.*?)(?=[\r\n\t\f ]*?\*\/|[\r\n\t\f ]*?-->)/ );`

Comment: @Luca You would use `.match`. `comment.match(/help::[\r\n\t\f ]*(.*?)(?=[\r\n\t\f ]*?\*\/|[\r\n\t\f ]*?-->)/)`

Comment: @Luca You could also use `comment.replace(/\/\*[\r\n\t\f ]*help::|<!--[\r\n\t\f ]*help::|[\r\n\t\f ]\*\/|[\r\n\t\f ]*-->/g, '');`

Answer (score 3):

You can add more languages as needed:

```
help::.*?\s(.*)(?:.*?\s\*\/|.*?\s\-->)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/rK2kU0/1

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = '<!-- A comment -->';
var newstr = str.replace(/<\!--(.*?)-->/, '$1');
console.log(newstr);  // A comment
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2):

```
    var regExArray = [['\\/\\* help::','*/'],['<!-- help::','-->']]
var regexMatchers =  regExArray.map(function(item){
                        return new RegExp('^'+item[0]+'(.*)'+item[1]+'$')})

function RemoveEndingTagsNew(comment){
    var newComment;
    regexMatchers.forEach(function(regEx,index){
        if(regEx.test(comment)){
        newComment=comment.replace(/.* help::/,"").replace(regExArray[index][1],"")
       }
    });
    return newComment || comment;

}
```

Its longer version, but doesnt remove comments if starting and ending comment tags doesnt match.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6bbxzyjg/2/